# SYSTEMTIME equivalent for linux

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-2010, cross-platform

I am doing cross-platform compilation of a huge solution written in C++ from VS2010 to linux environment.

My question is: what is the closest equivalent of struct SYSTEMTIME in linux ?

```
typedef struct _SYSTEMTIME
    {
    WORD wYear;
    WORD wMonth;
    WORD wDayOfWeek;
    WORD wDay;
    WORD wHour;
    WORD wMinute;
    WORD wSecond;
    WORD wMilliseconds;
    }   SYSTEMTIME;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at ctime(3) and related functions.  The struct tm appears to be a close match to the _SYSTEMTIME structure.

```
       struct tm {
           int tm_sec;    /* Seconds (0-60) */
           int tm_min;    /* Minutes (0-59) */
           int tm_hour;   /* Hours (0-23) */
           int tm_mday;   /* Day of the month (1-31) */
           int tm_mon;    /* Month (0-11) */
           int tm_year;   /* Year - 1900 */
           int tm_wday;   /* Day of the week (0-6, Sunday = 0) */
           int tm_yday;   /* Day in the year (0-365, 1 Jan = 0) */
           int tm_isdst;  /* Daylight saving time */
       };
```